# Is any Gauss-Markov assumption violated by the simple OLS regression transformation?

Tags: regression, gauss-markov-theorem

I am creating a simple linear model with the following form:
$$ y_i/x_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + u_i $$

The response variable has different name other than $y/x$, but it is essentially normalized by X as shown above.
So if the response, by definition includes part of the predictor can I regress this response on X, without introducing problems of bias or inefficiency? If no, can I have help with the intuition?

Comment: Depends. Look at the data. The model could make sense for e.g. does a rate depend on size, or does shape depend on size. In general ratios can be very problematic because division by small  numbers can impart skewness or create outliers -- or ratios can be entirely appropriate because scaling by a denominator creates the outcome measure you do want.

Comment: thanks Nick, but looking at my question more the specification seems a little strange. If y is say market returns and X is its volatility it seems that increases in volatility will guarantee a smaller normalized returns and vice versa. I assume that the coefficient would be near -1. So although the model makes sense, I feel like its cheating in some way. I suspect that this one predictor would absorb all the predictive power if I added other predictors of market returns. The point about outliers and skewness is very helpful. thanks

Comment: I am sure there is an interesting specific question in there about returns but in essence you need to spell it out and pitch it at like-minded economists.

Comment: Note that we often dive straight into this model. If you regress pandemic death counts scaled by population against population that is a different and more challenging hypothesis than whether pandemic death counts are affected by population size, to which the answer is Yes, of course they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is equivalent to:
$$y_i=\alpha x_i+ \beta x_i^2+u_i x_i .$$

Note $\varepsilon_i = u_i x_i$, such that this model rewrites:
$$y_i = \alpha x_i + \beta x_i^2 + \varepsilon_i .$$

So the two differences with a usual linear regression model are:

- you don't have a constant term,
- the errors $\varepsilon_i$ are proportional to the covariates $x_i$.

I don't think that the absence of constant term is a big deal (maybe I'm wrong...), but the other point is.

To have Gauss-Markov theorem, you want the $\varepsilon_i$ to have:

- null expectation,
- constant variance,
- null covariance.

In order to have that, you need assumptions on you $x_i$ (which you don't need to have Gauss-Markov theorem for a classical linear regression).
Such assumption could be that the $x_i$ are independent from the $u_i$ and have constant mean and variance. Then you'll have that the $\varepsilon_i$ satisfying the three conditions.

So, as Nick Cox commented, the answer is: it depends.
If you have a fixed design ($x_i$ are constant), then no (the $\varepsilon_i$ won't have constant variance). If you suspect the $u_i$ not to be independent from $x_i$, then no again.
But if the $x_i$ are i.i.d. and independent from the $u_i$, then I think yes.

Comment: I think this is misleading. By your logic, equivalent representations of the same model yield different conclusions. This should not happen. What if (1) $y$ actually is defined as $y:=zx$, meaning $z_i=\alpha+\beta x_i+u_i$ and (2) all of the Gauss-Markov assumptions are satisfied in this model which also happens to be the data generating process?

Comment: Hm... I do agree with you with your comment, but I cannot see where I wen't wrong in my reasoning. 
Your representation with $z_i = y_i / x_i$ and mine with $\varepsilon_i = u_i x_i$ clearly yield different conclusions.. Do they differ by some hidden assumption ?

I'm a bit lost now...

Comment: @Pohoua It seems to me your general logic is right but the last bit about when this is fulfilled may not be. It seems you (additionally) need $\epsilon_i=u_ix_i$ to be independent of $x_i$, which is not normally fulfilled if $u_i$ and $x_i$ are independent, but is fulfilled in Richard Hardy's case.

Comment: @Pohoua, in the second part of my point (2) I made an explicit assumption  regarding what the DGP is. You made an implicit one. If you state it explicitly, your argumentation would be justified. However, there is nothing in the OPs setup that justifies such an assumption. I am not saying that mine is justified either, but that only illustrates the problem with your answer in its current shape.

Comment: Sorry I still have difficulties to understand. If we have random variable $X$, $Y$ and $U$, saying that $Y/X = \alpha + \beta X + U$ is equivalent to saying that $Y= \alpha + \beta X +UX$. The assumed  data generating processes are the same..

Comment: But I'm quite convinced now that there is something fishy with my answer. Your argument is straightforward clearly right..

Comment: You have to add the assumption about the error term. E.g. I said "all of the Gauss-Markov assumptions are satisfied" for the model $z_i=\alpha+\beta x_i+u_i$. Also, please include @RichardHardy so that I get notified.

Comment: @RichardHardy I think I found what was puzzling me. 
I do think that the models $Y/X = \alpha + \beta X + u$ and $Y = \alpha X + \beta X^2 + u X$ are equivalent, and I couldn't understand why the second model requires more restrictive assumptions for the Gauss-Markov theorem to hold and have that the OLS estimator is BLUE.
But the OLS estimators for the two models aren't the same! In particular they are not linear with respect to the same response.

Comment: @RichardHardy 
OLS of the first model is linear in $Z = Y/X$, and it's the best unbiased among estimators linear in $Z$. 
The OLS estimator of the second model is linear with respect to $Y$ and is the best unbiased among estimators linear in $Y$ (if more restrictive aszumptions are made). 

As any estimator linear in $Z$ is also linear in $Y$, the class of estimator linear in $Y$ is wider. So OLS of the second model is best in a wider class, but at the cost of more restrictive assumptions!